# see client certificates with fiddler

Tags: fiddler, client-certificates

I have an application that calls a webApi.  My application must attach a client certificate to the request.  I can see the cert is attached in the debugger when I make the webApi call.  However, on the webAPI side there is no client certificate.

I would like to verify that the request has a client certificate when it leaves my applications

Is this something I can do with fiddler?
I only see options related to SSL server certs, or adding a client cert to a request made by fiddler.  Nothing about inspecting exiting traffics and seeing the client cert.